# How to keep SVG image scale/viewport on zoom in fabricjs version 2.x?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I upgraded fabricjs to 2.x and 3.x. in both version, when I zoom the canvas the svg image also scaling or viewport changing.

```
let greenCircle = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 50, fill: 'green', top: 110, left: 30 })
let orangeEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({ rx: 50, ry: 10, fill: 'orange', top: 12, left: 100, angle: 30 });
let group = new fabric.Group([orangeEllipse, greenCircle]);
canvas.add(group);
fabric.Image.fromURL(
  'https://gistcdn.githack.com/mudin/f633f3637b71b3dd9fcae1a88be27d8f/raw/850e8bf2baac6194bcf38190ca15defafb2ea2e7/floorplan.svg?raw=true',
  image => {
    image = image.scaleToWidth(1000);
    group.addWithUpdate(image);
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
);
canvas.renderAll();
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mudin/t2dz1ges/1/) in version 1.7.x

[not working](https://jsfiddle.net/mudin/3rt7zq69/20) in version 3.x

I checked the breaking changes in version2, but couldnt solve my issue.

Any help would be appreciated!